# Revert any changes of a resource to kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any command to revert back to previous configuration on a resource?

For example, if I have a Service kind resource created declaratively, and then I change the ports manually, how can I discard live changes so the original definition that created the resource is reapplied?

Is there any tracking on previous applied configs? it could be even nicer if we could say: reconfigure my service to current appied config - 2 versions.

EDIT: I know deployments have rollout options, but I am wondering about a Kind-wise mechanism

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're asking explicitly about the `last-applied-configuration` annotation...

Very simple:

```
kubectl apply view-last-applied deployment/foobar-module | kubectl apply -f -
```

Given that `apply` composes via stdin ever so flexibly — there's no dedicated `kubectl apply revert-to-last-applied` subcommand, as it'd be redundant reimplementation of the simple pipe above.

One could also suspect, that such a `revert` built-in could never be made perfect, (as Nick_Kh notices) for complicated reasons. A subcommand named `revert` evokes a lot of expectation from users which it would never fulfill.

So we get a simplified approximation: a `spec.bak` saved in resource annotations, ready to be re-`apply`'d.

Comment: Great workaround, just one question, what else is the usage of the `last-applied-configuration` annotation other than this, any official usage mentioned?

Comment: @Saad frankly speaking — no idea. Neither any idea if it's even possible to answer that comprehensibly; do you have more specific question in mind?.. Apart from the obvious use via `apply` as shown — try [searching github](https://github.com/search?type=code&q=%22last-applied-configuration%22) maybe; and for "official usage", search [over the k8s org](https://github.com/search?type=code&q=%22last-applied-configuration%22+org%3Akubernetes). Hope that helps. BTW it's no workaround; this is literal usage of the intended purpose of `kubectl apply` — to apply specs.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Kubernetes does not support rollback option for the inherent resources besides `Deployments` and `DaemonSets`.

However, you can consider to use [Helm](https://github.com/helm/helm), which is a well known package manager for Kubernetes. Helm provides a mechanism for restoring previous state for your package release and includes all entire object resources to be reverted.

This feature Helm represents with `helm rollback` command:

> helm rollback [flags] [RELEASE] [REVISION]

Full command options you can find in the official Helm [Documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-rollback).